# Screen Scraping Tool

Tags: screen, screen-scraping, ocr, tessnet2

I have used Screen Scraper Studio, which has an interop dll that allows you to pass in coordinates and it will scrape that region, I am literally trying to scrape just a 4 digit number, however this application requires quite an expensive developer licence. Are there any other programmes ready out of the box available with little coding required where I can just pass in some coordinates? I'd prefer not to use the TESSnet2 ocr package as it requires quite some setup with C#. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an alternative to screen scraper studio? What exactly you are looking to scrape and from where? I had similar situation few months back, and I used a simple drag and drop tool to scrape data. If that what you are looking for, I can give u some info.